# Android - check if layout exists

Tags: android, android-layout

Is there any way I can check if a certain layout ID exists before using it with setContentView(R.layout.mylayoutid)?

Something like:

```
if(layout_exists("mylayoutid"))
    setContentView(R.layout.mylayoutid);
else
    setContentView(R.layout.defaultlayout);
```

couldn't find anything in the developer docs.

Thanks!

Comment: Why wouldn't it exist? You can't dynamically generate new layout files

Comment: @mitai I don't understand that why would you want to check it in this way? Why would a layout not exist when you would have created it?

Comment: Ahmad, AndroidWarrior, I'm building an SDK that developers will use in their apps.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, there is.

```
int layoutId = getContext().getResources().getIdentifier("mylayoutid","layout", getContext().getPackageName());
if (layoutId == 0){
  // this layout doesn't exist
} else {
  setContentView(layoutId);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As it is a static integer in the `R.java` file you can't compile your app, if it does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

This function may helps

```
public static boolean checkLayout(Context context, int id)
{
     final View testView;
     try
     {
          testView = LayoutInflater.from(context)
              .inflate(id, null);

          return true;
     }
     catch (Resources.NotFoundException e)
     {
         e.printStackTrace();
         return false;
     }
}
```